# After starting Edge, all default apps reset to MS apps

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge, file-association

This is driving me nuts. Every time I (accidentally) start Edge, all default apps reset to the Windows defaults. So html pages and PDFs open in Edge. Text files open in Notepad (instead of what I had set it to). Music files open in the default music player. Etc.

I then need to manually set the default apps back to the apps of my choosing. How can I stop this annoying behavior?

Comment: Oy, gevalt! I can see how that would be highly annoying. I hope you get a good solution, though I'm not sure there is one. Can you delete the Edge icon to prevent accidental start-ups?

Comment: I set Defaults in Settings, Apps, Defaults and these settings stick.  Try running DISM and SFC as the initial repair. (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.   ..... Always run a full virus scan

Comment: This is certainly not my experience. Check if this happens when booting in Safe mode. If nothing helps, do [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Comment: **If** you do not want to use Edge, the easiest way to prevent it running is with Sordum's free Edge Blocker, https://www.sordum.org/9312/edge-blocker-v1-9/ . If you *do* want to run Edge on occasion,  Edge Blocker can allow that. Of course, this does not answer the question of *why* Edge changes defaults, nor will it remedy the default issue should you intentionally start Edge.